# Can getters be called from created hook in vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, getter

i have a getter that returns the total price in the basket. i need to call this getter the moment the component is first rendered. is it correct to call this getter in created hook?

```
created(){
    return this.$store.getters.getTotalPrice;
}
```

**getter**

```
getTotalPrice(state){
    for (let i in state.basket){
        state.totalPrice += state.basket[i].productPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you test it to see if it works?

Comment: yes i got error "getTotalPrice is not defined"

Comment: hi @ceren and welcome to SO
The answer to your question is yes you can 
i suggest you check the guide on how to ask a question on SO since this question will get downvoted soon... 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
probably the problem you are facing is not related to calling the getters in the created hook,

Comment: I agree that it should work.  There could be a problem with you Vuex store implementation, which you do not show.  Also, you are returning the getter in your created(), but not setting the return value to anything.

Comment: Also usually the getters are used to return a state here you are modifying the state maybe use actions instead ? 
and you should return something from withing the getter and in the created hook assign the value returned from the getter to a component variable maybe 
please state what are you trying to achieve so we can help you more

Comment: i want to show the total price of the products in state. but this has to be the moment the page loads.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide us with more code, the file where you create a vuex store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve this:

Vue component:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
       totalPrice:0
    };
  },
  created: function () {
    let self = this;
    self.totalPrice = self.$store.getters.getTotalPrice;
    console.log(self.totalPrice);
  },
};
</script>
```

Defining Getters in Vuex module:

```
const getters = {
  getTotalPrice: (state) => {
    let totalPrice = 0;
    for (let i in state.basket){
        totalPrice += state.basket[i].productPrice;
    }
    return totalPrice;
  },
};
export default {
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters
}
```

Comment: What's the point of doing referencing this to self? They will point to the same object.. if self.$store will work in your proposed solution. Then will this.$store work as well.